# Problem with login i can login with any username and password

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem with **login system** i can login with any **username and password** i dont how to fix

if anyone can help i would be very grateful

here my login system

```
function userLog() {
    global $connect;
    if(isset($_POST['userLog'])) {
        $username = trim(protect($_POST['username']));
        $password = trim(protect($_POST['password']));

        if(empty($username)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = '';
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } elseif (empty($password)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = '';
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();     
        }
        $userSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
        $userLog = $connect->prepare($userSQL);
        $userLog->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $userLog->execute();
        $userLog->fetchAll();

        #PLACE FOR SELECT DATA FROM SQL TO IMPORT TO SESSION
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $stm = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
        $row = $stm->fetch();
        ####################################################

        if($userLog) {
            $_SESSION['user_id']  = $row['user_id'];#id(mysql)
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];#user(mysql)
            $_SESSION['email']    = $row['email'];#email(mysql)
            $_SESSION['f_name']   = $row['first_name'];#fname(mysql)
            $_SESSION['l_name']   = $row['last_name'];#lname(mysql)

            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: SELECT the user with `username` then check the password against the rows password column. You dont need to fetch ALL the users and compare against the 1 row you selected. ALSO when did you setup the SESSION? That idea wont fly

Comment: Your `fetchAll()` does not put what it fetches (if anything) anywhere. You just cast it into the ether :)

Comment: There must be 1000 examples of a login script out on the web, or in the PHP Manual. I suggest you look for a few and have another try

Comment: setup SESSION is in diffect file

Comment: But if this user is Logging In, then their information should NOT be in the session... **because they are not yet logged in**

Comment: i logged with any username password i show me username of one user

Comment: Remember the session is linked to ONE External Connection not anything and everything that happens in your site

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CsjkdSF

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard i know this for test when i am finished i use password_hash thank you

Comment: I fixed this problem i forgot rowCount()

Comment: If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Thank you for your advice i am adding now security for password :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldnt go deep to create a class! you need to check for classes.

I just corrected your code as much as I can, I used bindParam instead of bindValue.

I hope you are using pdo, it show you are :) Please put `session_start();` on top of your page before everything else.

```
function userLog() {
    global $connect;
    if(isset($_POST['userLog'])) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if(empty($username)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Enter username';
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } elseif (empty($password)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Enter password';
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();     
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
            if($stmt = $connect->prepare($sql)){
                $stmt->bindParam(':username', $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $param_username = $username;
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $row = $stmt->fetch();
                    if($row['username'] === 1){
                        $hashed_password = $row['password'];
                        $email = $row['email'];
                        $name = $row['f_name'];
                        $lastname = $row['l_name'];
                        $id = intval($row['user_id']);
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            session_regenerate_id();
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id; 
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
                            $_SESSION['email'] = $email; 
                            $_SESSION['f_name'] = $name; 
                            $_SESSION['l_name'] = $lastname;    

                            header('Location: index.php');
                            exit();                             
                        }else{
                            $_SESSION['message'] = 'wrong password';
                        }
                    }else{
                        $_SESSION['message'] = 'wrong username';
                    }
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'User not found';
                }
            }else{
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Something went wrong';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I let you to do redirections to your error page

**UPDATE :** This is a simple class example, Search for proper way creating classes.

```
class userLog {
/** @var object $connect Copy of PDO connection */
private $connect;
/** @var object of the logged in user */
private $user;
/** @var string error msg */
private $msg;

    public function __construct($connect) {
        $this->connect = $connect;
    }  

    public function login($username,$password){
        $stmt = $this->connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? ');
        $stmt->execute([$username]);
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        if(password_verify($password,$user['password'])){
                $this->user = $user;
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['user']['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user']['fname'] = $user['fname'];
                $_SESSION['user']['lname'] = $user['lname'];
                $_SESSION['user']['email'] = $user['email'];
                return true;
        }else{
            $this->msg = 'Invalid login information';
            //you can change ajax response to session error
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

Usaqe : `$handle = new userLog($connect);`

Note this function requires ajax to return response.

Comment: Thank you explanation is very helpful

Comment: Hope it helps! You can ask if need more info, Use `$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` on registration to hash passwords.

Comment: I am using password hash now. I have question its important to have code like this if(empty($username)) {
        } elseif (empty($password))   
        }else {} or like this if(something) {} if(something) {}

Comment: You were using it right! See how I used in first codes in answer, I am on mobile so cant write codes. `if(empty($username)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Enter username';
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } elseif (empty($password)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Enter password';
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();     
        }else{ } `

Comment: Ok thank you... three dots due to the minimum number of letters

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not checking for any password so of course anyone can login, you should fix it like this:

```
$userSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :usr AND password = :pwd";
$userLog = $connect->prepare($userSQL);
$userLog->bindValue(':usr', $username);
$userLog->bindValue(':pwd', $password);
$userLog->execute();
$users = $userLog->fetchAll();

if(count($users) == 0) {
  // fail here, no one to login
  exit();
} elseif(count($users) > 1) {
  // Found more than one user, this should not happen, maybe fail.
}
```

If this check pass the user is logged in and furthermore `$users[0]` holds your user information

Comment: Except that still requires the password to be plain text... what *should* be done is for the `username` to be a `UNIQUE` index in the database, if not the primary key; you'd then select that user then use `password_verify()` to validate the password afterwards. Of course, that requires that the password was created using `password_hash()` in the first place ... which it should have been. You *shouldn't* be able to select on username/password in the first instance.

Comment: Many things should be done to improve this login system. But as for the current state and level I think this is a straight forward solution. I usually store the password hash and then perform a select on both username / userid and password_hash with the user inserted password hashed, so I'm never extracting the correct password hash from the db. As it makes no sense to do so unless you want to distinguish between 'Wrong username' and 'Wrong password' errors (which IMHO is a really bad thing to do).

Comment: We can even debate that by extracting the user from db to check the hash in the php environment my not be the best practice exposing your system to timing attacks,  where your script will perform the hash check only if the user exists, hence letting the attacker to understand if an username exists on your system just by timing your response time.

Comment: If you're using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` you don't know what the salt is until you've retrieved the hashed password from the database - so you *can't* select on it in your SQL query... or am I missing something?

Comment: No that is true, the second comment is actuable in an environment were you are using a global salt for your system. As in my opinion using a random salt for each password and storing it to the database with the password does not improove your system security at all (here I'm ready to be debated ;) )

Comment: Assuming that your db gets hacked a access to hashed pws and salts is gained hence by having many salts or one it makes no difference to an attacker that is trying to obtain the password of a specific user. The only difference is that in case of a single salt the 'cost' of obtaining all the passwords is lower, but still so high that it shall be negligible (assuming a strong hashing function is used). From what i hnow salts has the only purpose to transpose your hashes in another area of the hashing function that has no common lookup tables allready in place (as for simple plain passwords).

Comment: In the second case you still hash a concatenation of username + global_salt + password and again increase the cost to work back the entire dataset